# Porting Eclispse IDE settings

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I would like to use Eclipse as my IDE for C++ program develpoment.
Eclipse use "workspace" concept which I found difficult in terms of portability from one machine to another machine.

For example, I may have some custom settings made for one project and I would like to get the same settings even if I move the source code to some other machine and continue developmment there. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In ***Project > Properties*** you can enable and set project-specific settings. Technically, most of them are stored in the `.setttings` subfolder of your project, so they will be preserved when you copy the project folder to another computer or share it via a version control system.

Besides the `.setttings` folder, there are two important XML files in the root of the project folder, **`.project`** and **`.cproject`**. The file `.project` tells Eclipse that it is an Eclipse project and the type of project (C/C++, Java, PHP, ...). In the CDT-specific file `.cproject` the C/C++ project configuration is stored.

Example *C/C++ General > Code Analysis*:

[image]

The C/C++ project settings can be exported and imported via *File > Export/Import...: C/C++ Project Settings*.

If you want to store a **launch configuration** in your project, in ***Run > Run Configurations...*** select a launch configuration and in the ***Commmon* tab** switch to ***Shared file*** and choose a location within your project.

User-specific preferences (like shortcuts, colors and fonts, etc.) and other workspace preferences can be set in *Window > Preferences* and partially shared via *File > Export/Import...: General Preferences* or recorded via the Eclipse Oomph Preference Recorder and stored/synchronized via Eclipse.org (see [this short video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCsd681yo1c&t=24s)). Technically, these preferences are stored in the `.metadata` subfolder of the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what sort of settings you are talking about.

If you're talking about settings configured in `Window | Preferences`, those can be exported to a file using `File | Export | General | Preferences`, and imported into another workspace.

If you're talking about settings configured in `Project Properties`, one approach might be to check in the files that store these settings (`.project`, `.cproject`, and the `.settings` directory) into source control.

Comment: Thanks. But the question here is how to move the settings along with the source code. That is, I want to save the related  settings in the source folder itself!

Comment: @Soo I'm a bit confused. If you check `.settings` into source control, are you not "saving the settings in the source folder"?